# Flowing images into black hole animation

Tags: geometry-nodes, shader-nodes

How can I create this animation in Blender
https://www.shutterstock.com/tr/video/clip-1007814385-black-hole-absorbing-endless-dollar-flow-loopable
[image]

Comment: Hello, it could easily be done without Geometry Nodes, do you really need them?

Comment: Can you please explain how can I do it with or without geometry nodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a non-geometry-nodes solution. Create a cylinder, deform it:

[image]

Project your image on it, rotate the UV and change the *Mapping* scale value until you can't see anymore seam:

[image]

Animate the X and Y *Location* values of the *Mapping* node to make the image twirl:

[image]

Comment: Great, thank you!

Comment: I coudnt make it seamless, are there any trick to do it?

Comment: You need to rotate, then tweak the value that is plugged into the Mapping scale values it until it is seamless